# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Homebrewing Stack Exchange](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Posting this in the holiday period wasn't good timing - most people are quite busy then. I certainly was, and didn't get to look at the evaluation questions.

Comment: review is now 404

Comment: @CDspace the evaluation is available for 7 days only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What does a good crush look like, and does it matter if grains are overcrushed if batch sparging?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10908/what-does-a-good-crush-look-like-and-does-it-matter-if-grains-are-overcrushed-i)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Eggwhite as finings?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10977/eggwhite-as-finings)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [ReaLemon's preservatives](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10833/realemons-preservatives)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Yeast/Green Apple Taste](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/yeast-green-apple-taste)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Unsticking a secondary fermentation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10881/unsticking-a-secondary-fermentation)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [lots of moisture on the lid of the fermenter](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10885/lots-of-moisture-on-the-lid-of-the-fermenter)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Apple pulp. Can I leave it 24 hours?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10968/apple-pulp-can-i-leave-it-24-hours)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Noob here... My second brew - am I brewing an ale or a lager, and did I stuff it up?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10969/noob-here-my-second-brew-am-i-brewing-an-ale-or-a-lager-and-did-i-stuff-it)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Foam Overflow - Residue on Carboy walls](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10991/foam-overflow-residue-on-carboy-walls)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Lack of head/foam/carbonation in my beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11003/lack-of-head-foam-carbonation-in-my-beer)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

Comment: 10 questions, and only 2 votes, something is amiss

Comment: I agree - but I think many people simply miss the link - it's tucked off to the right, while most people's focus is on the left. I tend to only see the evaluation because it appears in the mods review page. Perhaps moving the notice to the top of the page, like they did with the "hats" would give it more focus.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the Stack Exchange form factor allows this, but it would be nice if we could pin to the right side of the page helpful things such as: (1) links to questions/answers/wikis to common "newbie" questions; (2) a link to a glossary of homebrew terminology and abbreviations; and (3) mathematical formulas useful in homebrewing.

Comment: www.reddit/r/homebrewing has something like this

Comment: Other SE sites use a [tag:faq] tag to create the same type of effect.  MSO has a very well laid out series of questions composing their FAQ.  Pinning is a bit forum-esque which SE tries to avoid afaik.  Also consider updating your [about] page to provide links to the FAQ and / or canonical questions.  For the math formulas, I would recommend opening another question here in meta and tag it as a support-request.

Comment: I don't know if we have an FAQ, but I certainly can't find it by searching for "FAQ". The comment on "pinning" makes sense. But the FAQ tag you suggest would work similarly. But we spend enough time answering basic questions that we ought to come up with an FAQ, maybe as a community wiki, and then tag it as an FAQ. It should answer questions such as "help, my airlock is not bubbling!", "is my beer infected?", and "help, my beer is flat!"

Comment: And I like the idea of updating the About page, both for more flavor on what this stack exchange is about, as well as linking the FAQ(s).

Comment: Post this as a separate [meta-tag:feature-request], please - and try to collect some links you think would be useful!